# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue for iPhone phone gap BarcodeScanner plugin

Tags: iphone, cordova

[image]Hi i want to  run iPhone phone gap BarcodeScanner plugin in the device. I am getting this error while i am running my application. I did every thing mentioned in the Zing and BarcodeScanner plugin document. I am getting this error while i am build the application  'zxing/common/Counted.h' file not found in /Users/celstra/Desktop/final/ZXingWidget/Classes/FormatReader.h     so can any one guide me.
Only one error i am getting .I have attached out put of this application . Please find the output picture.

Answer (score 0):

The project is not set up correctly. The include search path is not pointing at the zxing cpp directory (`cpp/core/source`). Either there's no entry in the project file for that path or the cpp directory is not where it should be.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. i did every thing . I set the cpp path and zing path also . I checked ZXingWidget/Classes/ and cpp/src... etc  . But it is  showing above issue.That is zxing/common/Counted.h' file not found error

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell you what's wrong with your setup, but the error is definitive: the include path is wrong. You could try checking out the standard zxing distribution (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/checkout) and build that and then see if you can figure out what's different.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I had originally checked out just the iphone directory from zxing's SVN trunk.  After failing to fix (without trying any of the complex solutions), I decided to blow away the project, and download the entire zxing SVN trunk.  After that, make sure you read the README to add library and dependency.  All was well after that.